# Arrange letters to avoid consecutive positions

Tags: combinatorics

Given 7 letters: a,a,b,b,c,d,e, how many possible ways are there for us to arrange them so that matching letters are not in consecutive positions? (e.g. aabcdbe) is not legal.

I tried to solve the question by finding the total possible ways first. If there's no restriction, then there're $\frac{7!}{2!2!}$ ways. Here we don't want $aa$ and $bb$ appear in the string, so we need to subtract $2\cdot\frac{6!}{2!}$ from $\frac{7!}{2!2!}$. Is that right? Did I miss any unwanted cases? Thanks for the help!

Comment: you need to apply principle of inclusion exclusion for the method you have chosen.

Comment: When $aa$ are together, you will also count cases that have $bb$ together too, right?

Comment: @Math Lover Yes! So can I exclude that by subtracting the number such that aa and bb come together? like $2\cdot6!/2!-5!$?

Comment: @Math Lover Then there're 600 unwanted cases in total?

Comment: No when you subtracted $2 \cdot \cfrac{6!}{2!}$, you subtracted those cases where $aa$ and $bb$ are together twice so you need to add it back.

Comment: $\frac{6!}{2}$ already has those cases. But you subtract it twice. So add back $5!$ once.

Comment: @Math Lover Thanks, so should that be $2⋅6!/2!+5!=840 $?

Comment: $\frac{7!}{2! 2!} - 2 \cdot \frac{6!}{2!} + 5!$

Comment: @Math Lover Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Laguerre polynomials have some remarkable combinatorial properties and one of them is precisely suited to answer problems of this kind. This is nicely presented in *[Counting words with Laguerre series](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.6232v1.pdf)* by Jair Taylor. We find in section $3$ of this paper:

> **Theorem:** If $m_1,\ldots,m_k,n_1,\ldots,n_k$ are non-negative integers, and $p_{m,n}(t)$ are polynomials defined by
> \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{n=0}^\infty p_{m,n}(t)x^n=\exp\left(\frac{t\left(x-x^m\right)}{1-x^m}\right)
>   \end{align*}
> then the total number of $k$-ary words that use the letter $i$ exactly $n_i$ times and do not contain the subwords $i^{m_i}$ is
> \begin{align*}
>   \int_0^\infty e^{-t}\prod_{j=1}^k p_{m_j,n_j}(t)\,dt
>   \end{align*}

Here we consider an alphabet $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and words built from the letters $$a,a,b,b,c,d,e$$

**Bad words:** $\{aa,bb\}$

We have $m_1=m_2=2, n_1=n_2=2$ and we obtain with some help of Wolfram Alpha

\begin{align*}
p_{2,2}(t)&=[x^2]\exp\left(\frac{t\left(x-x^2\right)}{1-x^2}\right)\\
&=[x^2]\left(1+tx+\frac{1}{2}(t-2)tx^2+\cdots\right)\\
  &=\frac{1}{2}t^2-t
\end{align*}

The letters $c,d,e$ contribute according to the paper $t^3$ and it follows

\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\left(\frac{1}{2}t^2-t\right)^2t^3\,dt=660}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Please apply Principle of Inclusion Exclusion as we discussed in comments. Alternatively, given the number of letters is small, you can also count them as follows -

First place c, d, e as  `_ c _  d _ e _` and so there are $4$ places for next letter. Now let's place `a`

Case $1$: both `a` are separated. So we choose two places for them. That is ${4 \choose 2} = 6 \ $ ways. That gives us $6$ places to choose from for two `b` and that is ${6 \choose 2}$ ways. We can then permute `c d e` in $3!$ ways.

So total number of permissible arrangements = $ \displaystyle {4 \choose 2} {6 \choose 2} 3! = 540$

Case $2$: we place `aba` together in one of the four places between `c d e` or to its right or left. After placing the block `aba`, we now have $5$ places to choose from for the last `b`.

So total number of permissible arrangements = $ 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 3! = 120$

Adding both cases, we have total of $660$ arrangements.

Answer (score 2):

Successively apply the well known "gap" and "subtraction" methods.

Keep the $B's$ separate by placing them in the **gaps** of $-A-A-C-D-E-$ and permute the other letters, thus $\binom62\cdot\frac{5!}{2!} = 900$ ways.

Now **subtract** arrangements with the $A's$ together treating them as a super $\mathscr A:\;\;-\mathscr A-C-D-E-,\;\;$ i.e. $\binom52\cdot4!= 240$ ways

Thus ans  $= 900-240 = 660$ ways

For small problems, I find this to be the simplest approach

Answer (score 2):

Fix $aa$ in one of the $6$ places. Then there are $\frac{5!}{2!}$ arrangements for the rest $5$ letters.

Similarly, fix $bb$ in one of the $6$ places. Then there are $\frac{5!}{2!}$ arrangements for the rest $5$ letters.

There are $5!$ arrangements for $aa$ and $bb$.

Hence, using the inclusion-exclusion principle, the arrangements with $aa$ or $bb$ is:
$$n(aa \text{ or } bb)=n(aa)+n(bb)-n(aa \text{ and } bb)=6\cdot \frac{5!}{2!}+6\cdot \frac{5!}{2!}-5!=600$$
Thus, the final answer is:
$$\frac{7!}{2!2!}-\left(2\cdot \frac{6!}{2!}-5!\right)=1260-600=660.$$